# How can I convert a logfile entry date into a date in the future in bash

Tags: bash, date, datetime, date-arithmetic

I'm sure this answer is obvious but I'm banging my head on it and getting a headache and my Search Foo is failing me…

I have a log file with this date format:

```
Sep  1 16:55:00 stuff happening 
Sep  1 16:55:01 THIS IS THE LINE YOU WANT at this time stamp
Sep  1 16:55:02 more stuff
Sep  1 16:55:02 THIS IS THE LINE YOU WANT at this time stamp
Sep  1 16:55:03 blah
Sep  1 16:55:04 blah and so on…..
```

My ultimate goal is to:

1. Find the last line in the log file with a given string eg:  "THIS IS THE LINE…" this is my "magic time" that I will do calculations on later.
2. Take the date of that line and set a variable that is the date +NN  seconds. The time in the future will usually just short of 24hrs in the future from the time in step 1 so crossing into the next day may happen if that is important.
3. At some point in the script, advance the system clock to the new date/time after which I will be checking for certain events to fire.

I know this is way wrong but so far I have figured out how to:

1. Grab the last date stamp for my event.

   logDate=`cat /logdir/my.log | grep "THIS IS THE LINE" | tail -1 | cut -f1,2,3 -d" "`

**Returns: Sept 1 16:55:02**

1. Convert the date into a more usable format

   logDate2="$(date -d "$logDate" +"%m-%d %H:%M:%S")"; echo $logDate2

**Returns: 09-17 16:55:02**

1. I'm stuck here   - what I want is:

   futuredate=`$logdate2 + XXXSeconds`

Could someone help me with the time calculation or perhaps point out a better way to do all of this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> I'm stuck here - what I want is:
> futuredate=$logdate2 + XXXSeconds
> ```

You can do it by converting through timestamps:

```
# convert log date to timestamp
logts="$(date -d "$logDate" '+%s')" 

# add timestamp with seconds
futurets=$(( logts + XXXSeconds ))

# get date based from timestamp, optionally you can add a format.
futuredate=$(date -d "@${futurets}")
```

Answer (score 1):

```
# Get time in seconds from the epoc (1970-01-01 00:00:00 UTC)

dateinseconds=$(date +"%s" -d "$(tail -1 logfile | grep "THIS IS THE LINE" | awk '{print $1, $2, $3}')")

# You can also use just awk without grep and tail to match and print the last line
dateinseconds=$(date +"%s" -d "$(awk '{/THIS IS THE LINE/}END{print $1, $2, $3}' logfile)")

gotofuture=$(( $dateinseconds + 2345 ))  # Add 2345 seconds
newdate=$(date -d "@${gotofuture}")
echo "$newdate"
```